# как отправить письмо из джава приложения?

Tags: java, email, gmail

Подскажите пожалуйста, как отправить письмо из джава приложения?
отправлять нужно с моей почты (gmail.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел подробную инструкцию вот тут:

https://mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

```
//1. Gmail SMTP через TLS

SMTP = smtp.gmail.com 
Port = 587
SendEmailTLS.java



import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SendEmailTLS {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String username = "username@gmail.com";
    final String password = "password";

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //TLS
    
    Session session = Session.getInstance(prop,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(
                    Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("to_username_a@gmail.com, to_username_b@yahoo.com")
            );
            message.setSubject("Testing Gmail TLS");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                    + "\n\n Please do not spam my email!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```